# Drag SVG object from one canvas to another canvas

Tags: canvas, svg, drag-and-drop, raphael

I was wondering if it is possible to drag one SVG object from one canvas to a different canvas. I need to implement a web page that has multiple areas that need to be drawn with SVG, but this areas are placed in different parts of the page. The requirement is that I must drag objects from one area to a different area, so I am thinking to have multiple canvas areas on which I draw using SVG but I am not sure if I will be able to drag objects from one canvas area do a different canvas area. I was drawing objects with RaphaelJS one a canvas area and noticed that when dragging them outside the canvas they are not visible anymore, so my first thought is that this is not supported.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svg drawing is limited to the viewport (read: canvas) that's setup.

There are many ways to do what you want. E.g make a new svg image that you move under the mouse while dragging. You can also make sure that the svg canvas covers the entire window, but note that that won't give you dragging outside the window (if that's something you want).
Another more complete way is to use [HTML5 drag&drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) to set a dragimage and use the native functionality there.